# The “listener” argument must be of type Function. Something wrong with Node.JS 9.3.0_1 on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, https, node-modules

That's my code which I got from official documentations with some my modifications:

```
let file = fs.createWriteStream( "data/test.txt" );

let httpOptions = "https://google.com";
const req = https.request( httpOptions, ( response ) => {

    response.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => {

        response.pipe( file );

        file.on( "finish", () => {} )
            .on( "close", () => { file.close(); } )
            .on( "error", ( err ) => { console.log( "!!! Error: " + err ); } );

    } );

});

req.on( 'error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

I get: "The “listener” argument must be of type Function" on this line:

```
.on( "close", () => { file.close(); } )
```

What do I do wrong? I've added "close" handler so it should work fine but it's not.

Here's the full error:

```
    events.js:180
        throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'listener', 'Function');
        ^

    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function
        at _addListener (events.js:180:11)
        at WriteStream.addListener (events.js:240:10)
        at WriteStream.close (fs.js:2298:10)
        at WriteStream.file.on (/Users/.../myscript.js:229:32) <=== This is .on( "close", () => { file.close(); } )
        at WriteStream.emit (events.js:159:13)
        at fs.close (fs.js:2141:14)
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:149:20)
```

Node.js: 9.3.0_1, MacOS X: 10.12.5

**UPD:**
If I change these lines to new ones:

```
file.on( "finish", () => { } )
.on( "close", () => { } )
```

there are no any errors but the output file is empty. So node.js doesn't allow me to close the file properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate the error. If I take the code from your question, add the two `require` calls, and run it, I don't get the error (on *nix, not Mac OS, but they're very similar). But I also don't get data in the file.

Calling `pipe` *within* the `data` event doesn't make much sense. Instead:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");

let file = fs.createWriteStream( "data/test.txt" );
// *** Note moving the code setting up these handlers out of the `data` callback
// That said, since you're using `pipe`, I don't think you need the close handler,
// and your finish handler doesn't do anything
file.on( "finish", () => {} )
    .on( "close", () => { file.close(); } )
    .on( "error", ( err ) => { console.log( "!!! Error: " + err ); } );

let httpOptions = "https://google.com";
const req = https.request( httpOptions, ( response ) => {
    // *** Do the pipe
    response.pipe( file );
});

req.on( 'error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

If I do that, I get data (specifically, the text of a 302) in the file. (I also get it, and no errors, without adding any handlers to `file`.)

Comment: Your code also doesn't work for me :) It's not only my problem. I saw the same problem with Node.JS on MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962447/node-js-the-listener-argument-must-be-of-type-function

Comment: If I remove all the *file.close();* calls - then it works for me. And the output file is not empty!

Comment: @JavaRunner: As I said, you're calling `pipe`, so you shouldn't need to close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the error, even with the fixes on the accepted answer, then try to remove the https/http from your host. It's pretty strange but it make sense, as the http or https will be decided based on other things like port number and the module used.